# Is there such thing as a Perabyte?

Tags: storage, real-time, disk

I recently saw a marketing video that cited the "Perabyte" as a unit of disk storage measure. I emailed a representative responsible for the video and got a response that "1 Perabyte (PB) = 1024 Terabytes (TB)."

A quick google search seems to indicate that a *Petabyte* is defined as 1000 TB.

Is a Perabyte a real thing, and is it 1024 (vs 1000) TB?

Edit: This thread has answered my question, despite the votes to close. No one has heard of a "Perabyte" except as a misspelling of "Petabyte." Thanks.

Edit (2): *Petabytes* have been tagged real by "BRIGHT SIDE"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking for a general computer terminology definition.

Comment: Given that no search results clarify "Perabyte" vs "Petabyte" yet the misspelling is common enough to generate plenty of search results (and resultant confusion), this question seems to me to be worthwhile.

Comment: that doesn't make it on topic.

Comment: Is there another SE community that would be a better fit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perabyte doesn't exist, but a petabyte is a real thing. It is

> 2^50 bytes; 1024 terabytes, or a million gigabytes.

Comment: your answer was unrelated to OP's question

Comment: Why @DhruvPathak? It answers the exact question, no?

Comment: I guess you mistyped "Perabyte" as "Petabyte". Can you update your answer to correctness ? I will remove the downvote then.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- now I get it @DhruvPathak .. edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that your perabyte was the result of a typo, seeing as 'r' and 't' are close on the keyboard.

The 1024 versus 1000 question most likely arises from which base you are using. 
1024 is base 2, 1000 is base 10.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte

Answer (score 1):

A [petabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petabyte) is 1000<sup>5</sup>, or 1000 [terabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terabyte).
A [pebibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebibyte) is 2<sup>50</sup>, or 1024 [tebibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte).

A perabyte is not a thing.